# How i can get actual comments count without blocked and hidden comments?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, comments

I have facebook comment box  widget. This widget show comments and comments count on the top, it`s true count but if i get comments count from facebook graph api http://graph.facebook.com/?id=#my url#  api returned count from all comment with comments witch was blocked or hideen. How i can get actual information about comment from graph api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments

total_count can be greater than or equal to the actual number of comments returned due to privacy or deletion